# Php contact form, how to make it send with charset utf-8?

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I have the following php contact form code and it's working perfect except that it isn't sending with charset UTF-8, which I need for my language.

Anyone know how to make it send with urf-8?

Thanks in advance, Jack

```
<?php
$error    = ''; // error message
$name     = ''; // sender's name
$email    = ''; // sender's email address
$subject  = ''; // subject
$message  = ''; // the message itself
$spamcheck = ''; // Spam check
$telefon = ''; // telefon
$kategori = ''; // kategori

if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$message  = $_POST['message'];
$spamcheck = $_POST['spamcheck'];
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
$kategori = $_POST['kategori'];

if(trim($name) == '')
{ $error = '<div class="errormsg">Skriv in ditt namn.</div>'; }
else if(trim($email) == '')
{ $error = '<div class="errormsg">Skriv in din e-mail adress.</div>'; }
else if(!isEmail($email))
{ $error = '<div class="errormsg">Du har skrivit in en ogiltig e-mail adress. Försök igen!</div>'; }
if(trim($subject) == '')
{ $error = '<div class="errormsg">Skriv in ett ämne.</div>'; }
else if(trim($message) == '')
{ $error = '<div class="errormsg">Skriv in ditt meddelande.</div>'; }
else if(trim($spamcheck) == '')
{ $error = '<div class="errormsg">Svara på Antispam frågan!</div>'; }
else if(trim($spamcheck) != '5')
{ $error = '<div class="errormsg">Antispam: Felaktigt svar! 2 + 3 = ?</div>';}

if($error == '')
{
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{ $message = stripslashes($message); }

// the email will be sent here
// make sure to change this to be your e-mail
$to      = "";

$subject = '[Sigster] : ' . $subject;

// the mail message ( add any additional information if you want )
$msg     = "Från : $name \r\nE-Mail : $email \r\nTelefon : $telefon \r\nKontakta mig genom : $kategori \r\nÄmne : $subject \r\n\n" . "Meddelande : \r\n$message";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n");
?>
```

Comment: indeed, it works with header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: but it converts the whole page to utf-8, which I don't want to ;/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `Content-Type` header. Change the line :

```
mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n");
```

To :

```
$headers = array
(
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: ' . $email,
    'Reply-To: ' . $email,
    'Return-Path: ' . $email,
);

mail($to, $subject, $msg, implode("\n", $headers));
```

You can find [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#111124) a function to send utf-8 email.

Comment: where should I add it? at the top of thr script?

Comment: Just change your `mail()` line with my code. I edit my answer to show you (not sure for the indentation, you do not have)

Comment: I am getting an error message, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: I can not fix your code ! The idea is : keep all your code (from <?php to ?>), and just erase your `mail()` function with my code.

Comment: still getting the annoying message, I am suppose to replace my mail with your code right?

Comment: this line: mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n");

Comment: Yes, try to replace it with my code to see if it works.

Comment: still: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: Ok ok, my fault ! I forgot a parenthesis at the end of my `mail()` function :/